# ToC, chapter problem, adding a dot next to the number of chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

```
\documentclass[openany, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

%\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Spis}
    \renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\MyTitle{\scshape Pacjent i Analityk}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\scriptsize \textsc{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\scriptsize \textsc{\MyTitle}}
\fancyfoot[L,C,R]{}


 \frenchspacing

 %style form chapter
      %http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html
 \usepackage{pstcol}
 \makeatletter
     \def\LigneVerticale{\vrule height 5cm depth 2cm\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
     \def\LignesVerticales{
     \let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
     \def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{%
     \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
     \rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\white #1}\hss}}%
     \vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}

     \def\@makechapterhead#1{\hbox{%
     \huge 
     \LignesVerticales
     \hspace{-0.5cm}%
     \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
     \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
     \renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
   }\par\vskip 2cm}

   \def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
   \huge 
   \LignesVerticales
   %\hspace{0.5cm}%
   \hbox{#1}%
   }\par\vskip 2cm}

   \newcommand\MySquare{% thanks to Gonzalo Medina
     %http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina
   \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height .9ex width .7ex depth -.2ex\hss}}
   \renewcommand\labelitemi{\MySquare}

   \usepackage{titletoc}

   \title{Foo is getting older}
   \author{Joseph Bar}
   \date{}

   \begin{document}
   \maketitle



   \frontmatter
       \tableofcontents
\chapter*{Chapter whitout a number}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter without a number}

\mainmatter
    \chapter{Solution}\label{chap:one}
    \section{One}
    \section{Two}
    \section{Another section}
    \chapter{Second solution}
    \chapter{Third chapter}
    \chapter*{Chapter without a number}
    \section{One}
    \section{Two}
\end{document}
```

The goal is:

1. Put the dots next to chapter
    a) in ToC,
    b) in text
2. Get left marking work correct, meaning - I want a name of chapter, number of a chapter [with dot], but without a word:"Chapter"
3. Add dots from chapter to the page number in ToC,
4. Enumerate style change: from native to dark square with bold number inside

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below there's a possible solution: the `tocloft` package was used for 1)a) and 3). A redefinition of `\chaptermark` solved 2). A redefinition of `\labelenumi` using \fbox solved 4). Adding a dot after `\thechapter` in the already existing definition of `\@makechapterhead` solved 1)b). The code contains some comments showing where the changes were made:

```
\documentclass[openany, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}% adds dot after chapter title in ToC
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}% adds leader dots from chapter titles to page numbers

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Spis}
    \renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
\makeatother

\newcommand\MyTitle{\scshape Pacjent i Analityk}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\scriptsize \textsc{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\scriptsize \textsc{\MyTitle}}
\fancyfoot[L,C,R]{}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}} % chapter mark wothout "Chapter"


 \frenchspacing

 %style form chapter
      %http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html
 \usepackage{pstcol}
 \makeatletter
     \def\LigneVerticale{\vrule height 5cm depth 2cm\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
     \def\LignesVerticales{
     \let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
     \def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{%
     \rlap{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}%
     \rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\white #1}\hss}}%
     \vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}

     \def\@makechapterhead#1{\hbox{%
     \huge 
     \LignesVerticales
     \hspace{-0.5cm}%
     \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter.}% the final dot adds a dor after the chapter number in the document
     \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{#1}%
     \renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
   }\par\vskip 2cm}

   \def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
   \huge 
   \LignesVerticales
   %\hspace{0.5cm}%
   \hbox{#1}%
   }\par\vskip 2cm}

   \newcommand\MySquare{% thanks to Gonzalo Medina
     %http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina
   \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height .9ex width .7ex depth -.2ex\hss}}
   \renewcommand\labelitemi{\MySquare}

   \title{Foo is getting older}
   \author{Joseph Bar}
   \date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Chapter whitout a number}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter whitout a number}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{%
  {\setlength\fboxsep{2pt}\fbox{\bfseries\arabic{enumi}}}} %redefinition for first level labels of enumerate

\mainmatter
\chapter{Solution}\label{chap:one}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{One}
\section{Two}
\section{Another section}
\chapter{Second solution}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\chapter*{Chapter whitout a number}
\section{One}
\section{Two}

\end{document}
```

Some images of the resulting document showing the changes requested:

The ToC (dot after chapter number and leaders from the title to the page number):

[image]

A typical numbered chapter tile showing the requested ending dot; this image also shows the required formatting for the labels of the first level of an `enumerate` environment:

[image]

A typical even-numbered header showing the desired formatting (number-dot-title):

[image]