# ToC, article class, adding a dot next to the number of section

Tags: table-of-contents, article

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68665) question I would like to add a dot after the *section*-numbers in my table of content. However I am using the *article* class for which the solution mentioned in the link does not work. Is there a workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Add a symbol in ToC between the section number and its section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173553/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), using

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
```

inserts `.` after the `s`ectional unit `num`ber. For visuals (despite the different document class), the following example is a taken completely from [ToC, chapter problem, adding a dot next to the number of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68665/5764) with the above addition:

[image]

```
%...
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}% adds dot after chapter title in ToC
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}% adds leader dots from chapter titles to page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}% adds dot after section title in ToC
%...
```

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the macro `\numberline` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 5772:
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}
```

so you can add to your document preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}}
\makeatother
```