# Theorem and chapter with Dot at the end

Tags: sectioning, chapters, theorems, punctuation

I'd like to have dot at end of the number of chapter and at the end of the number of theorem.

I tried to use something like that:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definicja}[chapter]

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}

\begin{document}

    %EDIT
    \tableofcontents
    %END EDIT

    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    \begin{definition}
        Some content
    \end{definition}    
\end{document}
```

but theorem looks like this (two dots):
[image]

How to remove this dot in theorem after number of chapter and add dot at end of the theorem. It should be: `Definicja 2.1.`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Don't do it this way. Any reference to Chapter 2 will appear as `Chapter 2.`. For a standard document class, you might use `\usepackage{titlesec} \titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}` instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code sniped to small, complete document with start `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document} which will demonstrate your problem. By the way, the `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}` probably should be \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}\arabic{subsection}.}`

Comment: @Bernard I tried your solution and dot at end of the number of the chapter did not appear.

Comment: @Zarko I've just changed post according to your suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a dot after the chapter number in the title of the chapter only, you need to patch `\@makechapterhead`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\thechapter}% <search>
  {\thechapter.}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

To add a dot after the (any) sectional number in its title only, you can update `\@seccntformat`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother
```

The default display for a theorem defined under [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) is to end its number with a dot.

Here is a complete minimal example highlighting the above:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definicja}[chapter]

%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% Default
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}% Default

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\thechapter}% <search>
  {\thechapter.}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}% Just for this example
\chapter{Chapter}

\setcounter{section}{7}% Just for this example
\section{Section}

\setcounter{definition}{8}% Just for this example
\begin{definition}
Some content
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, generally works, but I have one more issue, there is no dots in table of content after number of chapter/section/subsection.

Comment: @Kedrzu: If you're using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) as in my answer, you can also add `\patchcmd{\numberline}{\hfil}{.\hfil}{}{}` to the preamble. If you're not using `etoolbox`, you can add `\makeatletter \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1.\hfil}} \makeatother`. Similar changes can be applied using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), or by writing the `.` when writing the ToC-entry...

Comment: Thanks, a lot! I just have found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187699/toc-article-class-adding-a-dot-next-to-the-number-of-section) another solution, with tocloft: `\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}`
`\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}`. Accepted as answer, unfortunetly I have no rights to vote.